# rake db:migrate not working// I flollowed many suggestions but still not working :(

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing ruby on rails tutorial, and having trouble migrating database. 
I did $rails generate devise user then rake db:migrate. but it didn't work I did $rails destroy devise user then generated again. Now when I do rails generate devise user, I get three files under migrate. and db:migrate still doesn't work. 
This is very frustrating. 
I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the migration files are missing the `.rb` extension.  Rename them to add the extension.  For example, rename `20150305030528_devise_create_users` to `20150305030528_devise_create_users.rb`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't work. I will try again, should I do that for all three of them?

Comment: Yes, rename them all.

Comment: I deleted two of them, and renamed it, putting rb at the end, now it says rake aborted don't know how to build task .